# Original version of a passage by Gogol'

Tags: перевод, узус

For quotation purposes, I would like to find the original (Russian) version of the following passage from the novel *Dead souls* by Nikolaj Gogol' which in English looks like:

> In all the world, you will find no joys like these, for herein man imitates the God who projected creation as the supreme happiness, and now demands of man that he, too, should act as the creator of prosperity. Yet there are folk who call such functions tedious!

Such a passage should be found in Chapter III of the second part of the book. I would be interested in a translitterated version from Cyrillic, if possible (for LaTex issues).

Just an aside remark, in case you may be wondering or it may be needed: I have no knowledge of Russian language at all (and this is also the reason why I find it difficult to look for the original passage).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cyrillic:

> Да в целом мире не отыщете вы подобного наслажденья! Здесь, именно здесь подражает Богу человек. Бог предоставил себе дело творенья, как высшее всех наслажденье, и требует от человека также, чтобы он был подобным творцом благоденствия вокруг себя. И это называют скучным делом!

Paste it here: http://translit.net/ for transliteration in any standard you need.